# Azure Data Factory - convert flattened dataset to json objecy

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a flat file as a source in Data Factory with this data.

```
State, City, Zip
OH, Cleveland, 44110
OH, Cleveland, 44126
WA, Seattle, 98102
```

I would like to build a json file (sink) with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "State": "OH",
    "City": [
      {
        "city": "Cleveland",
        "zip": "44110"
      },
      {
        "city": "Cleveland",
        "zip": "44110"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "State": "WA",
    "City": [
      {
        "city": "Seattle",
        "zip": "98102"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

I'm using a Copy Data task and am getting stuck on the mapping in the Sink.

Any direction you can point me?

Answer (score 0):

Only Copy data activity won't give the desired output. As it requires operations with rows and columns, you need to use a combination of Dataflow and copy activity to get the expected results.

First, take your source dataset as dataflow source and then use **Aggregate transformation** to group by the `State` column.

[image]

And in **Aggregates** section use the `collect()` to create the `City` array with below expression.

```
collect(@(city=City,zip=Zip))
```

[image]

Now, create a JSON dataset and give your location path to it. Add this to the Dataflow sink and, in the settings, give the below configurations to store it in a single file.

[image]

When you execute the dataflow activity from pipeline, the result JSON file will be created as objects like below.

[image]

So, to get the **Array of Objects** type JSON file, after the dataflow activity use **copy activity with same JSON dataset as source and sink**. In sink of copy activity, set the **File Pattern** as `Array of Objects` like below.

[image]

Now, Execute the pipeline, and you will get the desired output JSON.

[image]